# How to deal with categorical data that has 35 unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, categorical-data

I am working on IPL cricket dataset which has data about batting stats for all the teams over by over.

I want to visualise how different cricket grounds affect the total score of the batting team. I try to plot a simple scatter plot but the stadium names are too long and it does not show the names clearly.

Do I have to convert the 35 values into numeric values? It prints nothing when I try to find correlation with the target variable.

The data set:
[image: The dataset]

The problem with reading the plot (the x-axis):
[image: The problem with reading the plot(the x axis)]

Comment: you can rotate text, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the font and/or rotate it: https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc

Answer (score 1):

You can make your plot bigger by setting figsize.
(add this at the first line):

```
plt.figure(figsize(14,8))
```

and then rotate the xticks. (at the end):

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```